# Ternary concatenation in Twig

Tags: twig, ternary-operator, string-concatenation

Is it possible to use ternary operator in Twig when concatenating one string to another if some condition is true?

This works for me:

```
{% set a = 'initial' %}
{% if foo == bar %}
     {% set a = a ~ ' concatenate' %}
{% endif %}
<p>{{ a }}</p>
```

But when I try to simplify it like this, it throws an error:

```
{% set a = 'initial' ~ (foo == bar) ? ' concatenate' : '' %}
<p>{{ a }}</p>
```

Am I doing something wrong or this simplification is simply not possible in Twig?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

due to the order of [precedence](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#twig-expressions) you'll need to add parentheses, 
`{% set a = 'initial' ~ ((foo == bar) ? ' concatenate' : '') %}`

---

If the 2nd part is empty you can even omit it e.g.

```
{% set b = 'initial' ~ ((foo == foo) ? ' concatenate') %}
```

[twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/sh1n9f)